# Tag/Fulltext-Search in MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-search

As you can read from the headline, I'm working on a project which should offer a search-option. The user should type in a few single keywords and the results should be listed by relevance. Because my database has around 1k-2k rows, I need this to be as exact as possible. 
Researches pointed out to make more tables which contain the tags for the rows. I made a prototype for this, but it would be timecounsuming to do this for every single row now because the database altready exists. I've read that making some kind of "crawler" would be a possibiltiy? I've also heard that using ISAM-Databases would be a option.

Can anyone suggest me a possible solution? Or maybe some examples?

I have a basic understanding of PHP and MySQL.

Kind regards,
Force0234

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add **FULLTEXT INDEX** to all your searchable fields and use **MATCH ... AGAINST** keywords

```
SELECT * FROM searchable_table WHERE MATCH(searchable_field) AGAINST('Keyword');
SELECT *, MATCH(searchable_field, searchable_field2) AGAINST('Keyword') as Relevance FROM searchable_table WHERE MATCH(searchable_field, searchable_field2) AGAINST('Keyword');
```

Note: you can use few fields in **MATCH(...)** and use it in SELECT clause for get the relevance. Don't hesitate to use it twice, MySQL will optimize the query.

Please, refer the MySQL documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

Comment: Thank you! I guess that will help me go on :))

Comment: In that case - mark Answer as valid and applicable. Thanks!